# How to change background color based on user input and algorithm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to make a website with my friend that converts Celsius to Fahrenheit. We currently have it so you input the number in one box and it comes out the other unit the other box.

**We want the page to change color if the entered Celsius or Fahrenheit is above or below a certain number.**

Thank you for your help :)

Current code:

```
<p><input id="c" onkeyup="convert('C')"> degrees Celsius</p>

<p><input id="f" onkeyup="convert('F')"> degrees Fahrenheit</p>
<script>
function convert(degree) {
    var x;
    if (degree == "C") {
        x = document.getElementById("c").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
        document.getElementById("f").value = Math.round(x);
    } else {
        x = (document.getElementById("f").value -32) * 5 / 9;
        document.getElementById("c").value = Math.round(x);
    }


}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK...can you post those certain levels and corresponding colors or is arbitrary values ok?

Comment: Change the background color of what? What colors? What number? Please try to at least attempt to do this yourself. Hint: you'll need to look into the [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property of the element whose background you wish to change.

Answer (score 2):

## `<meter>` Thermometer

I'm assuming you are making a thermometer. See this **[link](https://css-tricks.com/html5-meter-element/)** for details on how to sync attribute values to the CSS `background-color`s.

---

### HTML

**Tags**

- HTML5 `<meter>` tag is an ideal element.
- Changed the `<input type="text">` to `<input type="number">`

**Meter Attributes**

- `max="140"`
- `min="-51"`
- `high="99"`  100℃ Boiling point of H<sub>2</sub>O - **gold to red**
- `low="1"`        0℃ Freezing point of H<sub>2</sub>O - **gold to red**
- `optimum="23"` 23℃ Room temperature

---

### JavaScript

- Changed `keyup` event to `input` event because it's faster and specialized for `<input>` tags.
- One line added to JavaScript to control the `<meter>` tag:

  ```
    thermo.value = t.c.value;
  ```

  If applied to OP code the equivalent would be:

  ```
    document.getElementById('thermo').value = document.getElementById("c").value
  ```
- `if/else if/else` condition sets a range of 15.5℃ to 26.5℃ (60℉ to 80℉) - The range is styled by `.comfortable` class. **green to gold**.

---

### Demo

```css
#case {
  margin: 20px 40px 40px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width: fit-content;
}

#case label {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 53% 531%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

label {
  display: block
}

#thermo {
  width: 200px
}

meter::-webkit-meter-bar {
  background: #e6e6e9;
}

meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
  background: gold;
}

meter.comfortable::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
  background: green;
}

meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value {
  background: red;
}

meter::-moz-meter-bar {
  background: #e6e6e9;
}

meter::-moz-meter-optimum-value {
  background: gold;
}

meter.comfortable::-moz-meter-optimum-value {
  background: green;
}

meter::-moz-meter-suboptimum-value {
  background: red;
}

#thermo {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<form id='temp'>
  <label><input id="c" oninput="convert('C')" type='number' max='140' min='-51' value='23'> ℃</label><br>

  <label><input id="f" oninput="convert('F')" type='number' max='290' min='-60' value='75'> ℉</label>

  <fieldset id='case'>
    <label for='thermo' data-max='140' data-min='-55' class='C'>℃</label>
    <meter id='thermo' max='140' high='99' low='1' min='-55' value='23' optimum='23' class='comfortable'></meter>
    <label for='thermo' data-max='290' data-min='-60' class='F'>℉</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
  var temp = document.forms.temp;
  var t = temp.elements;
  var thermo = document.getElementById('thermo');

  function convert(degree) {
    var x;
    if (degree === "C") {
      x = t.c.value * 9 / 5 + 32;
      t.f.value = Math.round(x);
    } else {
      x = (t.f.value - 32) * 5 / 9;
      t.c.value = Math.round(x);
    }
    thermo.value = t.c.value;
    if (thermo.value >= 15.5 && thermo.value <= 26.5 && !thermo.classList.contains('comfortable')) {
      thermo.classList.add('comfortable');
      return false;
    } else if (thermo.value < 15.5 || thermo.value > 26.5 && thermo.classList.contains('comfortable')) {
      thermo.classList.remove('comfortable');
      return false;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works okay, -7 degrees C after entering 100 degrees C the color stays red

Comment: Okay I see. Makes sense thanks for clarifying. It threw me off a little when it went above 100 and then I went to -7 and the color didn't change but I reread the OP and I see why you did it that way. Good Job!

Comment: Thank you, sir. It's the `<meter>` tag that does the heavy lifting. :)

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to accomplish this is to add/remove a class to a div and set the background color that way.

for example:

```
 <style>
      .red{
           background-color: red;
      }
      .blue{
           background-color: blue;
      }
 </style>

 <div id="parent">
      <div id="inner_div"></div>
 </div>

 function convert(degree) {
      var x;
           if (degree == "C") {
                x = document.getElementById("c").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
                document.getElementById("f").value = Math.round(x);
           } else {
                x = (document.getElementById("f").value -32) * 5 / 9;
                document.getElementById("c").value = Math.round(x);
           }

           if(x<threshold){
                $('.parent').addClass('blue');
                $('.parent').removeClass('red');
           }
           else if(x>=threshold){
                $('.parent').addClass('red');
                $('.parent').removeClass('blue');
           }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add another conditional statement inside of your function that adds a CSS class to the body (or whichever element you'd like). Here's a start. I haven't tested but it should point you in the right direction.

degrees Celsius

```
<p><input id="f" onkeyup="convert('F')"> degrees Fahrenheit</p>
<script>
function convert(degree) {
    var x;
    if (degree == "C") {
        x = document.getElementById("c").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
        document.getElementById("f").value = Math.round(x);
        if(x > 30) {
            $(body).addClass('scorching-red');    
        } else {
            $(body).addClass('blue');
        }
    } else {
        x = (document.getElementById("f").value -32) * 5 / 9;
        document.getElementById("c").value = Math.round(x);
        if(x > 80) {
            $(body).addClass('scorching-red');    
        } else {
            $(body).addClass('blue');
        }
    }


}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way in vanilla JS is to check the value of `celcius` input box (just to pick one), comparing to a threshold and change the background color of the `body`

```js
function convert(degree) {
  var x;
  let celciusInput = document.getElementById("c");
  if (degree == "C") {
    x = celciusInput.value * 9 / 5 + 32;
    document.getElementById("f").value = Math.round(x);
  } else {
    x = (document.getElementById("f").value - 32) * 5 / 9;
    celciusInput.value = Math.round(x);
  }
  
  let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  let temperature = +celciusInput.value;
  if (temperature >= 38) {
    body.style.background = "red";
  } else {
    body.style.background = "cyan";
  }
}
```

```html
<p><input id="c" onkeyup="convert('C')"> degrees Celsius</p>

<p><input id="f" onkeyup="convert('F')"> degrees Fahrenheit</p>
```

Comment: Your code works okay, but when you enter a 100 degrees Fahrenheit the color is blue, not red like most would think it would be as 100 degrees Fahrenheit is pretty warm

Comment: @MGoward fair enough, I lived in the desert for a few months and 100 deg F was considered a cool day though =]. I've updated my answer since 38 makes more sense as a threshold. Thanks for your input.